# Calculating height of NSAttributedString with constraint on height

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

Method [NSAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:options:context] allows to define the height needed to draw the entire content of the string. 
I would like to have constraint on height and find precise height less or equal given value of height and allowing to draw the same amount of text that would fit if a label had height equal to constraining value.

How can I try to accomplish this task?

And the similar task is when constraint on height is set via number of lines. That is it is needed to find height of attributed text with given width and given max number of lines.

Thank you in advance for you answers.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Is your text multi-lined? And you're trying to round the height needed to the nearest line shorter than the constrained height?

Comment: @Fennelouski: that's what I got, yes: work out how much of the original text will fit in that height, work out height of that amount of text.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution might just be to set the number of lines on your `UILabel` by calculating the height of one line and then dividing your total height by the single line height. It's a bit naive, but it should do the trick.

Here's my implementation of that suggestion:

```
// Whatever your initial string is, attributes and all
NSAttributedString *myAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"My Really Long String" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont systemFontSize]]}];

// The frame that you want the label to fit in and not clip text
CGRect maximumFrame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX, MY_MAXIMUM_HEIGHT);

// This takes the attributes and assumes an infinitely wide frame and gives you a height
CGRect myStringBoundingRect = [myAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:maximumFrame.size
                                                     options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine
                                                     context:nil];

NSInteger numberOfLines = 1;

// This assumes the text has no line breaks in it and the text is only one line
if (myStringBoundingRect.size.height > 1 && myStringBoundingRect.size.height < maximumFrame.size.height) {
    numberOfLines = (NSInteger)(maximumFrame.size.height / myStringBoundingRect.size.height);
} else { // remove all line breaks and find the height for only one line
    NSRange rangeOfLineBreak = [myAttributedString.string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

    if (rangeOfLineBreak.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSAttributedString *mySubstring = [myAttributedString attributedSubstringFromRange:rangeOfLineBreak];
        myStringBoundingRect = [mySubstring boundingRectWithSize:maximumFrame.size
                                                         options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine
                                                         context:nil];

        if (myStringBoundingRect.size.height > 1 && myStringBoundingRect.size.height < maximumFrame.size.height) {
            numberOfLines = (NSInteger)(maximumFrame.size.height / myStringBoundingRect.size.height);
        }
    }
}


UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:maximumFrame];
myLabel.attributedText = myAttributedString;

// Set the number of lines to match the maximum number of lines that fit in your frame
myLabel.numberOfLines = numberOfLines;

// resize the label
[myLabel sizeToFit];
```